# Solving a differential equation on the torus $\mathbb{T}^1$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, periodic-functions

I'm interested in solving the following equation, on the torus $\theta\in[0,2\pi]$,

$$\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
\ \ \ \ \ \ \  \phi_t=f(\theta)|\phi_{\theta}|,\\
\phi(\theta,0)=\phi_0(\theta).
\end{array}\right.$$

Here, every function appearing is a $C^1$ function on the torus, i.e., a $2\pi$-periodic $C^1$ function.

My goal is to give an example of $f,\phi_0$ such that the solution $\phi=\phi(\theta,t)$ exists, but the spatial derivative $\phi_{\theta}$ is NOT uniformly bounded in time.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe $\phi_t=\frac{1-\theta^2}{1+\theta^2}|\phi_\theta|$, so that $\phi$ grows at small $\theta$ but smoothens out for large values.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the function $f(\theta)$ needs to be periodic.

Comment: It is if you take $[-\pi,\pi]$ as the domain. Otherwise shift the variable $\theta$.